# Wrong edition of python2.7 interpreter when I configure Pycharm remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I am now configuring remote interpreter when I use Pycharm 2017.3. My remote Python2.7 interpreter's path is `/opt/apps/python/2.7.10/bin/python2.7`, but when I use `ssh` to configure remote interpreter, Pycharm tells me this interpreter is Python 2.7.5!!! And I can't use it to run my code! (because i don't download relevant libs under 2.7.5) More interesting, when I enter `/opt/apps/python/2.7.10/bin/python2.7` on my terminal (mac shell), it shows:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Apr  7 2017, 10:43:09) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Woo, i dont know the reason~ Who can tell me? Thank you!

Comment: what does `ssh <hostname> 'which python'` show?

Comment: /opt/apps/python/2.7.10/bin/python2.7

Comment: i am using a cluster, when i log in, it shows "head"